# Creating an exclusive union from a mapped type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a strongly typed map that holds the types of possible arguments to a function.  I can create the argument types for said function by using mapped types to create a union of the types of the original map's values.  The problem I have is trying to find a good way to make those arguments exclusive, i.e., so that a consumer can't "mix and match" fields from the different values of the type.  This will make more sense with a code example.

Here's the strongly-typed map (NB: in actual usage these maps and their types are programmatically generated, which limits what I can do to them, i.e., I can't go in an add discriminants or manually change their typing):

```
type MyMap = {
  foo: Foo
  bar: Bar
  baz: Baz
}

type Foo = {
  x: number
  y: number
}

type Bar = {
  a: number
}

type Baz = {
  l: number,
  j: number,
  k: number
}

// A type-erased version of it to use for constraints
type SomeMap = Record<string|number|symbol,Record<string,any>
```

And here's an example of a function that will use the types of the map's properties as possible arguments:

```
type Args<T extends SomeMap> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K]
}[keyof T]

function foo<T extends SomeMap>(args:Args<T>){
    //do something
}
```

Now, this doesn't work, and the reason is because TS unions are not exclusive.  So while this will fail (because `z` isn't in any of the sub-types):

```
foo<MyMap>({z: 5})
```

this won't (because it mixes and matches parameters from `Foo` and `Bar`):

```
foo<MyMap>({x:1, y:2, a:1})
```

My question is what's the best way to "fix" this, i.e., to only allow arguments that match the object literals of `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`?

I've read the [TS comments on the `XOR` proposal](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094), and I think I get the idea behind a solution, namely, some conditional type that forces the non-selected type properties to `undefined`, but I can't seem to get it to work here.

I tried to define an `ExclusiveArgs` type as follows:

```
type ExclusiveArgs<T extends SomeMap> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] & NotAnyOthers<T,K>
}[keyof T] 

type NotAnyOthers<T extends SomeMap, K extends keyof SomeMap> = {
  [Z in keyof Omit<T,K>]: MakeUndefined<Omit<T,K>[Z]>
}[keyof Omit<T,K>]

type MakeUndefined<T extends Record<any,any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: undefined
}


function bar<T extends SomeMap>(args:ExclusiveArgs<T>){
    //do something
}
```

This doesn't work, i.e., now even "correct" examples fail unless I spell out the values, including `undefined` for every possible parameter.  I'm guessing this is because TS otherwise doesn't know which type I'm "aiming" for.

Any ideas on how to make my solution work or a better/more elegant solution?  I realize it would probably be easier if `Foo`/`Bar`/`Baz` had discriminant fields in them, but I don't have any way to add those in this environment.  That said, it is guaranteed that they will not have overlapping properties (i.e., `Foo` and `Baz` won't have the same field `x`)

Working examples of the problem, my attempt to solve it, and how it fails are in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=70&ssc=1&pln=55&pc=1#code/PTAEEFQZwFwJwPYDsDmAbAngWhhgDgKYAmoAtgIZ4A0oAlkqDABYGhwHlqiV6NO1Q6gvIhRxypCjFoBjTpgCwAKBCgUBJAXExi3JCWatchQeXZ0kAMy3siNKAjLkkAV3kZQxWtNR8CUAmVVY38hJAByGD1QBDxpZGUQ0ABZDGTKUABeUABvZVBQSwQEAC5QADFi-NAAIzMygCEzarqAL0byVuUAX2VE-FZKx2y8pQKADzLXUhqtaowplxm5pV6lfsJQJrgs3OryReW4Hr6lJKbW3dGCtEPZuCpqgCs7rUex0ABrV%20PV09VICEsFpyAESAA3LRQWjIGKWOhRGCOFwBQoIHYyZCwcT0GBQDasADKCFIBHSvGyACUCJi4EQADzY%20goAA%2003uLKgGBmCDQVGptIZTNQVGcGAAfOL-mAACosUCYpAyAhxMpiuF%20Qq0AhoIiCBDw4mk8kK5y1Vgo3Sg6JmFBLDQwIJgBA1J40xGOciFFxK%20JIAkQOAoKD0mWecY6fSCI1kyjiq7VADaAGkLF8CBgDaAZQBdMoylM5nqJz4ZrO56UVYpCaIEcYSPBoVhZr2WH0yP18chROQMGDkUt6DxZwyMAb6w0k2N4cL4lRgESxLTSULW7ymIP2pCOpRt30whhFBCh8ORvWgGPk8UACltUBK4CDIZl4oAlNcCqAQERHA5ScxmROdZ52zfhTDQLgAHd0U%20UxBDrQgO2IZQj3pVIr2vHJJlAABGGgFgAJm6V8UOKNC0jjTCDlw4jSOPdDKJyW5cKoF4CJob4AGZaPnAABPFgXGRCYGBOBEF%20VCGLwG8cnaUAAFYeKdUCBFAH9-AiKIbHRLAcCYbtZ24Ds3AgjwEPdXRZjkS1s0JUAfQPDdWCQBAd1UOsZDQFFaEhGhaAAOgIfyaGtNBkBQbhBFHSxtV1eDxgEKJ6BiTQNVHBzYVJI451UbxQEg2gINAPBQSgfyCjlVgAEcXH8TtVKYBBIMYRwKEHPKHE1Qg4FIbwdBIW0tzxZSWHMMxWA8rzoV8uhAuC6BHAAwRLHIQrTB7Ek8EKggcFoUl-Lo8iMKwko8NAQiQtOpSQIAdQACXAMMAElwgANQAUWzSknvegARUBdNrcZPO8yEx02Zhu24GAdFIOIoscIo4GVTUYp1c8RxYZTXNG%20ykAPMgCGylq8aIAgYs0IgAwAOVc8AkAwAB5Qw4GfU8NHPS9KBoVM6zPQRS0zSdjTjBMPkTAAtNNBazRnepgUMqGTcU8xSAcCAAVX0cn6GIek5e8RXlclnMpVWEsy3hA2FZlJWVdOJJ0lLLWyYpvWwz5jnBAFdEGTFUUGclMWChTaXLezVWfVd3Wqb%20YCkne4Gpp8ghH2DE9PajC8pyvYPQFD5KZfhXN80LUAADJQFpmB6aZlnnzt4si4j0BThQ9tOzqOAM4jL3s5F6TbyfEpE5B6bU6fUM3w-Apv1-KcANQIDlIaDWZX8jeETUhANMifKYOULujsY7CzsInij6kmTqJwi%20zGPwemLKPC2I4kpuJIviBPMjtRPEw-75X0wnJRSn8AHdyASdM%20JR2LcCup-IAA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by adapting your example a little bit. The key peice is instead of forcing the additional properties to be `undefined`, allow them to be *optional* `never`. This will make it so that those additional keys *must* be omitted in the passed object. For example:

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never;

// Here is the magic type, it will allow objects of type Base as long as they contain no properties from any of the "Extras".
type RefuseExtras<Base extends Record<string, any>, Extras extends Record<string, any>> = Base & {
        [K in keyof UnionToIntersection<Extras>]?: never;
}

// The use of Omit here gives the RefuseExtras type one part of the union as the Base, and the remaining parts as Extras.
type ExclusiveArgs<OptionsMap extends Record<string, Record<string, any>>> = {
        [K in keyof OptionsMap]: RefuseExtras<OptionsMap[K], Omit<OptionsMap, K>[keyof Omit<OptionsMap, K>]>
}[keyof OptionsMap]
```

Then, you will get errors when specifying additional properties on any of those types, but they work when defined exactly:

```
function bar<T extends MyMap>(args: ExclusiveArgs<T>){
    //do something
}

// All works!
bar({a: 2})
bar({x: 10, y: 20})
bar({l: 1, j: 2, k: 3})

// But then:
bar({a: 10, x: 10}) // Type '{ a: number; x: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Baz': l, j, k
bar({x: 10, y: 10, f: 1}) // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'f' does not exist in type 'RefuseExtras<Foo, Bar | Baz>'
```

However you can still specify additional properties *not present* in the other parts of the union if you don't use an object literal. The restriction only applies to properties on other members of the union:

```
const withF = {x: 10, y: 10, f: 1};
bar(withF) // Works

const withA = {x: 10, y: 10, a: 1};
bar(withA) // Still errors: Type '{ x: number; y: number; a: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Baz': l, j, k
```

---

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiMEMxQLxQN4CgpQGYHt8AuKAMUOygCMEAnEgITspoC9GFXMBfTTUSGUKoMlAB4kAdgFcAtlQi1KIKXIVLe-cNCa0RWHAlXzFPPgJ2d9lADbH1AGkoAre4qc4A1m43ntUAFVJAEt8SQAVfABJSWBFAGcIAGNgUMkAHgCAPhEACgCoCDE4yQATeKgESRAoAH4oXO9AgEoULIA3fGDSqCkIdsVmwuKIMorcxpJgyVxFKCjWjq7Sofqo3qhJftMtQQBRMSSbaXjggYBBWgBzePSAeTBUsPjEZCKS8qgAJWT8WlL0vFgLRplcHN9fv9AcDQeCqiAsojrDgUSiANoAaSg0ygnggIHwuCgDyekheSAAuiQfrgThADsCELcSWlyWBMRTwXdZMFgPdHqzXuCMVk0XiCUTubz%20aS2cKshSsjwxfjCcSBc9XhS-IIaXSGbQmekmIlhh8Kj8kn8AUCQZIwZVqllwQamWbRp9LdboXaHfCkWgTdAAGSiVGozHYyS41VEoJpSIxOK0RIpNLpV3xBW1PoDWgAbjMmFpkjTYWodHS4XdY1g8CQWVydBuJAORxOZwglxuVayzQMKIA9IPSvgoPF8LIIMAABagos0Wi5dBGKAAJm4zUwi%20XEigAEYAAzglTrw%20b7d0Zd2A-g1zr8FNADMF8vS5XJCP4L3R4vO-QP7HlAp5fngn6vlaZLAFAADuvIzqQ%20iASen5Abg4FvrkcGzqQW6YJBQKwfB5xIahKEHkBq77twhY7thM7nHhQA)

Comment: Very helpful.  But why is the UnionToIntersection conversion needed?

Comment: For the "Extras" we need to combine all the properties from the other parts of the union into a single object we can map through. So if `Base` is `Foo`, then extras has to be `Bar & Baz`, so that we can extract the keys from both types. Basically because `keyof (Bar | Baz)` will be `never` (since they share no keys in common) but what we need is `keyof (Bar & Baz)`, which would be the union of strings: `"a" | "l" | "j" | "k"`.